# Delete product with filter in Localstorage

Tags: javascript, html, filter, local-storage, shopping-cart

I'm working on a shopping cart project and I'm stuck at the product removal stage.

I tried to work it with the filter method and it works without really working in the sense that what I defined works only in the case where the product having a dataset id and equivalent to the id of the localstorage but that the color is different then there the deletion of the selected product works and the localStorage is updated.

On the other hand when I want to delete a product having a different id but which has the same color as the product selected previously it deletes both products.

An example :
If I have a sofa that has an id 001 and a blue color and I have another sofa that has an id 002 and a blue color and I press the delete button then both products disappear...

How can I avoid this?

I think the definition of the condition I wrote here is a little shaky but I don't know yet how to fix it:

```js
const deleteProduct = function ()
{

      let deleteButton = document.querySelectorAll('.deleteItem');

      let localStorageProducts2 = localStorage.getItem('Produits')
      // Loop to get all buttons
      for (let i = 0; i < deleteButton.length; i++)
      {
            // More clear for the syntax
            let buttons = deleteButton[i];

            // Link each button to his article
            let myActualProduct = deleteButton[i].closest('article');
            let getStorageProducts2 = JSON.parse(localStorageProducts2);   

            buttons.addEventListener("click",() =>
            {       
            
                getStorageProducts2 = getStorageProducts2.filter(productsInLocalStorage => productsInLocalStorage.id === myActualProduct.dataset.id && productsInLocalStorage.colors !== myActualProduct.dataset.color);
                // Update the localStorage
                localStorage.setItem('Produits',JSON.stringify(getStorageProducts2));
                myActualProduct.remove()
                alert('Le produit a bien été supprimé')
                // Reload the page
                window.location.href ="cart.html";  
                  // Update the productsInLocalStorage
            
            })
      }
}

deleteProduct()
```

```html
<section id="cart__items">
               <article class="cart__item" data-id="{product-ID}" data-color="{product-color}">
                <div class="cart__item__img">
                  <img src="../images/product01.jpg" alt="Photographie d'un canapé">
                </div>
                <div class="cart__item__content">
                  <div class="cart__item__content__description">
                    <h2>Nom du produit</h2>
                    <p>Vert</p>
                    <p>42,00 €</p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="cart__item__content__settings">
                    <div class="cart__item__content__settings__quantity">
                      <p>Qté : </p>
                      <input type="number" class="itemQuantity" name="itemQuantity" min="1" max="100" value="42">
                    </div>
                    <div class="cart__item__content__settings__delete">
                      <p class="deleteItem">Supprimer</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </article> 
            </section>
```

The HTML part doesn't work here in JSFiddle , I'm working with an API on local.

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution by myself thanks to an article teaching how to use findIndex on array of object and the splice method.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).